# Reading a properties file in a Maven test

Tags: eclipse, maven, integration-testing

This seems like such a silly question but no solutions I've found online have worked for me.  I'm writing an integration test in a Maven project, and I need to read values from a properties file, which I've put in `src/test/resources`.

My test tries to read this properties file during construction:

```
public ControllerIT() throws Exception {
  wc = new WebConversation();
  prop = new Properties();
  InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/test.properties" );
  prop.load( stream );
}
```

When I run the test, I always get a `NullPointerException` on the call to `prop.load( stream );`.

I've tried just about every permutation of solutions that I've found online:

- Referencing the file as `test.properties` instead of `/test.properties`
- Getting the input stream via `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "test.properties" );`

But nothing works.

And I guess for extra points, the ideal solution would allow me to run this test via `mvn integration-test` on the CLI as well as in Eclipse via `Run As` -> `JUnit test`.  To that end, I guess I should also mention that I've explicitly added `main/test/resources` as a source folder in Eclipse, but it's still not loading the file correctly.

And as requested, here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>listener-testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>listener-testing</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Failsafe configuration for running integration tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Surefire configuration for generating reports -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>failsafe-report-only  </report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.x</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see, this is a stand-alone integration test suite (it basically just sends POST requests to a web service).  I run it with `mvn verify` and see:

```
$ mvn verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building listener-testing
[INFO]    task-segment: [verify]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
Downloading: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/simple/vm/junit/junit/debian/junit-   debian.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'junit:junit:pom:debian' in repository libs-release (http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/libs-release)
Downloading: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/simple/vm/junit/junit/debian/junit-debian.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'junit:junit:pom:debian' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] [failsafe:integration-test {execution: default}]
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /home/jmp/desktop/listener-testing/target/failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.integration.ControllerIT
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.156 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.integration.ControllerIT
testRequest(com.example.integration.ControllerIT)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:354)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:342)
        at com.example.integration.ControllerIT.<init>    (ControllerIT.java:30)


Results :

Tests in error:
  ControllerIT.<init>:30 » NullPointer

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] [failsafe:verify {execution: default}]
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /home/jmp/desktop/listener-testing/target/failsafe-reports
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/jmp/desktop/listener-testing/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 14 10:13:04 GMT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/125M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this output, line 30 of `ControllerIT` is the call to `prop.load( inputstream )`.

Comment: Please show your full pom file and the location of toue property file. How do you start the integration tests? Do you use `mvn verify`?

Comment: Added POM and maven output.

Comment: The seemed to be related with this: `[INFO] Unable to find resource 'junit:junit:pom:debian' in repository libs-release (http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/libs-release)
Downloading: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/simple/vm/junit/junit/debian/junit-debian.pom` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is of packaging type pom. That way, resources-plugin is not included in lifecycle (and no resources will be copied over to target and thus land in the classpath)

Change your packaging to `jar`, and everything should work.

Comment: Ha!  I originally was using a packaging of `jar` when I first ran into thi sproblem.  I changed it to `pom` because I didn't want it to attempt to run unit tests (since there are none).  It looks like I didn't use a package of `jar` with the right combination of ClassLoader and/or path to the properties file.